# How to calculate the minimum RAM & minimum Stake required for a new account?

Tags: accounts, eosjs

In the browser via eosjs, I have made the below function adapted from [the docs](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs#new-account) but how do I calculate the minimum RAM in bytes, stake_net_quantity and the stake_cpu_quantity?

I understand these values will change overtime?
If so then I need to calculate them every-time just before making the transaction.

```
_makeAccount(eos, ownerPublicKey, activePublicKey, creatorAccountName, newAccountName){

// eos = the eos object initialised with the creatorPublicKey
// ownerPublicKey = 'EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV'
// activePublicKey = 'EOS6MRyAjQq8ud7hVNYcfnVPJqcVpscN5So8BhtHuGYqET5GDW5CV'
// creatorAccountName "helloeosblox"
// newAccountName = "mynewaccount"

eos.transaction(tr => {
  tr.newaccount({
    creator: creatorAccountName,
    name: newAccountName,
    owner: ownerPublicKey,
    active: activePublicKey
  })

  tr.buyrambytes({
    payer: creatorAccountName,
    receiver: newAccountName,
    bytes: 8192
  })

  tr.delegatebw({
    from: creatorAccountName,
    receiver: newAccountName,
    stake_net_quantity: '10.0000 EOS',
    stake_cpu_quantity: '10.0000 EOS',
    transfer: 0
  })
})
```

}